# asp classic to use google charts

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, google-visualization

I have an asp page that loads ms sql information, and now i want to try to graph the information. I did some searching around and it seems google charts is what everyone says for a nice simple free solution. The issue is I am not sure how to work it in from my asp page. I want to start over and make a new chart page based on my asp classic page but not sure what to do. Here is my asp classic page. I am looking at the getting started for google charts but can't understand it in terms of preparing the data.

Here is my connection string I can't figure out how to write that in for google charts.

```
<%
ConnString="Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=192.168.1.84,1433; Network Library=DBMSSOCN; Initial Catalog=DLIDEV;  User Id=sa; Password=Passw0rd;"
%>
```

and my asp code for the sql statement i want to recreate I am confused as to how to convert this as they stated the from clause is no longer in use. And I can't find a guide to use google charts from asp classic.

```
<%
set conn = server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Connection")     
conn.Open ConnString

Set passGroupMoRS = Server.CreateObject( "ADODB.Recordset" )
passGroupMoRS.ActiveConnection = Conn


sqlString =  "SELECT ModelGroup, COUNT(SerialNumber) as TotalUnitsPassed  FROM PreQcFormTable WHERE (Date BETWEEN '"& dateOne &"' AND '"& dateTwo &"') AND (ProductOrigin = 'P') AND (FailCodes = '') Group BY ModelGroup"
SET passGroupMoRS = Conn.Execute (sqlString)
IF NOT passGroupMoRS.EOF AND dateOne <> "" THEN
%>

<%=passGroupMoRS( "ModelGroup" )%>  : <%=passGroupMoRS( "TotalUnitsPassed" )%>
```

Thank you for your time.

UPDATE: This is how i wrote up the javascript containing the chart. When i load the page it doesn't give me an error the chart just doesn't show up. this is based off google charts pie chart example.

```
<!--Jquery --> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!--Load the AJAX API--> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">    
// Load the Visualization API library and the piechart library.  
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});   

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded. 
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart); 

// Create the data table.       
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();       
data.addColumn('string', 'ModelGroup');    
data.addColumn('number', 'FirstyieldModelPassed');  

data.addRows([   
<%
WHILE NOT RSchartrmn.EOF
%>

  ['<%=RSchartrmn( "ModelGroup" )%>',<%=RSchartrmn( "FirstyieldModelPassed" )%> ],

<%
RSchartrmn.MoveNext
WEND
%>

<%
ELSE
%>
 ['Nothing', 0],  
<%
END IF
%>
 ]);        
 // Set chart options       
 var options = {'title':'First Yield by Model Number',    
 'width':400,                      
 'height':300};       
  // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.     
   var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));       
  chart.draw(data, options);     }    
  </script>
```

When I source the page on firefox i get the following information, Is there something wrong with the information?

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
// Load the Visualization API library and the piechart library.
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
// Create the data table.
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'ModelGroup');
data.addColumn('number', 'FirstyieldModelPassed');
data.addRows([
['7200',4 ],
['8300',1 ],
['8500',1 ],
['9200',2 ],
['9300',4 ],
]);
// Set chart options
var options = {'title':'First Yield by Model Number',
'width':400,
'height':300};
// Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options); }
</script>
```

And this is the div I have for the asp page.
    <"div id="chart_div" style="width:400; height:300">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see Google Charts talks to the Google API by means of client side Javascript.  You shouldn't need to change your connection string as it's talking to your own database.

Let's take the code example on this page on their [developers guide](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart)

The data is contained in this js fragment

```
function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
          ['2004',  1000,      400],
          ['2005',  1170,      460],
          ['2006',  660,       1120],
          ['2007',  1030,      540]
        ]);
```

If you wanted to use data from an ASP recordset then it would look like this- assuming of course that you have database table fields with names corresponding to the headings

```
function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
             <% do while not rs.eof %>
              ['<%=rs("year")%>',  <%=rs("sales")%>,       <%=rs("expenses")%>]<% 
               rs.MoveNext
                  if not rs.eof then response.write "," & vbcrlf end if
                  loop
               %>
            ]);
```

Edit - this client side code works for me

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
       var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'ModelGroup');
        data.addColumn('number', 'FirstyieldModelPassed');
        data.addRows([
        ['7200',4 ],
        ['8300',1 ],
        ['8500',1 ],
        ['9200',2 ],
        ['9300',4 ]
        ]);

        var options = {'title':'First Yield by Model Number',
        'width':400,
        'height':300};

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried something like that 

// Create the data table.       
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();       
   data.addColumn('string', 'ModelGroup');    
   data.addColumn('number', 'FirstyieldModelPassed');  
  
   data.addRows([   
 <%
WHILE NOT RSchartrmn.EOF
%>
                                    
  ['<%=RSchartrmn( "ModelGroup" )%>',<%=RSchartrmn( "FirstyieldModelPassed" )%> ],
 
<%
RSchartrmn.MoveNext
WEND
%>
                           
<%
ELSE
%>
 ['Nothing', 0],  
<%
END IF
%>
   ]);        
But I am not getting anything to show , I am not getting a error though.

Comment: Keep in mind i am trying it with the pie chart example. not the column chart

Comment: I added the script containing the chart i want to show, it doesn't give me an error just doesn't show.

Comment: The code for the piechart is almost identical, except that it uses `var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart...` rather than `var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart...`  What does View Source show - does the js look right

Comment: I know i added the chart script to see if it helps, maybe i wrote the script wrong somewhere. It is based off the pie chart example.

Comment: One thing which is easy to miss in their example - does the div id match the id specified in document.getElementById - ie if you're using  `document.getElementById('piechart')` then you need to use `<div id="piechart">` later on

Comment: I added the js above to show how i wrote it the source shows the info but it isn't displaying it i will display what the source says maybe i am missing something else.

Comment: I left the div alone so its should be using the same div.

Comment: Note that in their example there is no comma at the end of the last row of data after the "]" - your code will insert one.  I've just tried adding that extra comma and it does stop the graph appearing. If you execute your page and do a view source you should be able to see the javascript which your asp code generates without the asp

Comment: The purpose of my line `response.write "," & vbcrlf` is to remove that final comma.  I'm sure there are other ways, but it needs some sort of if not rs.eof logic

Comment: oh i do  notice that there is a comma showing in the last line. So i should just use your line

Comment: JS always bites you like that - I hate it

Comment: yeah when i try that i get this error.

Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a040e'

'loop' without 'do'

/searchYieldPreQcRevisedChart.asp, line 60

loop
^

Comment: oh okay i need to use the <% do while not rs.eof %> or just remove the loop

Comment: I am noticing something now with the changes the comma at the end is still there and i see the commas now showing up as a new line like this ['8700,4} new line then it adds the 
            ,    
And it still isn't showing up on my page.

Comment: OK, I've edited my answer, Check the line which puts in the comma.  The line breaks shouldn't matter but the source is easier to read if it's nicely formatted, so I've moved the <% up a line to immediately after the closing ] in the recordset loop

Comment: With your changes I am now trying it your way with the while and the Do where should the Expected 'End' be because thats where my error is at.

Comment: Alright Got the comma working now and the end statement closed but, it still isn't showing up on my page. I will try make a new page and just see if I can atleast load the chart and from there see what is wrong.

Comment: `if not rs.eof then response.write "," & vbcrlf end if` - Have you included "end if" at the end of this line

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49652/discussion-between-gilbert-v-and-john)

Comment: Yes John I have, The issue now i am getting is while the information is formatted correctly as according to source it won't load still, I made a seperate page to see if i can get it to load just that information and i can't get that to work. However the format is correct. When i replace the information with the example the example does load. I am wondering if i need a button or something to load the chart or something.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ASPGoogleCharts` class: https://github.com/rcdmk/ASPGoogleCharts

Disclaimer: As you can see from the URL, I'm the author.

```
dim chart
set chart = new GoogleCharts

chart.type = CHART_COLUMN

chart.title = "Friday Night Pizza"

dim rs
set rs = createObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.open "SQL HERE", yourConnection, 0, 1

' No need to declare columns. It gets the type and label from the Recordset.Fields property.

chart.loadRecordSet rs
chart.draw

set rs = nothing
```